# What is the difference if I use class with init vs record with init?

Tags: c#

Here I have this code. Both also I have `init`.

The first one is `class`. second one is `record`.

```
class Student
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string? Name { get; init; }
}

record Student2
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string? Name { get; init; }
}
```

Both student and student2 property also immutable after initialized. so then what is the difference if I use class with init vs record with init?

Comment: Why should there be an explicit difference for init? Are you asking what the difference between record and class is?

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://thecodeblogger.com/2021/11/26/c-record-how-is-it-different-from-classes/

Comment: The properties are immutable, but the default Equals operator will be different. 
On the class Student, the Equals will return true if the 2 references point to the same object.  On the record Student2, Equals will be true if all properties are equals, even if it's not the same references